# Python boolean operations on lists - inconsistent results

Tags: python, list, boolean, operator-keyword

Suppose I have two lists:

```
>>> y
[False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
>>> z
[False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

Then I do the following:

```
>>> y or z
[False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
>>> z or y
[False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
```

Shouldn't the correct answer be as shown below?

```
[False, True, True, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False, True]
```

I also get incorrect answers with `and`:

```
>>> y and z
[False, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, True]
>>> z and y
[False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False]
```

I tested 1s and 0s with odd results:

```
>>> y=[0,0,0,0,0]
>>> z=[1,1,1,1,1]
>>> y or z
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> z or y
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> y and z
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> z and y
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: try wrapping your lists in a bool call like `bool([False])` to understand why this happens

Comment: As the answers suggest, `or` does not work this way. However `numpy.logical_or` does work like this, so may be useful for you. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach for `or` operation:

```
[a or b for a, b in zip(y, z)]
```

The correct approach for `and` operation:

```
[a and b for a, b in zip(y, z)]
```

`None, False, 0, '', (), [], {} and few more` (mentioned here -> [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)) are considered `False`.

here's some example:

`[]` is `False`, `[False]` is `True` since its not empty, check using
 `bool([False])`

```
>>> [] and [False]
[]
>>> bool([] and [False])
False
```

`[]` is `False`, `[False]` is `True`, hence Here `True`

```
>>> [] or [False]
[False]
>>> bool([] or [False])
True
```

Answer (score 6):

`y or z` doesn't behave how you think it does, on the individual elements. Instead, it evaluates the 'truthiness' of the first argument (`y`). Since `y` is a non-empty list, it evaluates to true. The overall statement then evaluates to `y`.

Similarly, `z or y` first looks to see if z is truthy (which it is, because it's a non empty list). Thus the statement evaluates to `z` without ever looking at `y` or the elements within it.

Here are some clearer examples:

```
>>> [1,2,3,4] or [5,6,7,8]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> ['this','is','a','list'] or ['and','here','is','another']
['this', 'is', 'a', 'list']
```

An empty list evaluates as 'false-y', so in this care, the right hand list is the value of the statement:

```
>>> [] or ['and','here','is','another']
['and', 'here', 'is', 'another']
```

Swapping the order of the lists shows that the first one to evaluate as true will be the result:

```
>>> ['and','here','is','another'] or ['this','is','a','list']
['and', 'here', 'is', 'another']
```

To achieve what you want, you could do a list comprehension like

```
[
    y_item or z_item
    for y_item, z_item
    in zip(y, z)
]
```

Comment: or `[any(items) for items in zip(y,z)]`

Comment: Using `any` returns the boolean value and not the 'truthy' list value itself, which may or may not be what the OP wants.